# How to capture data between a repeating string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
'request=1417935385131095&to%5B%5D=596254125&to%5B%5D=683330370&e2e=%7B%22submit_0%22%3A1394711375644%7D'
```

I want the data between "&to%5B%5D=596254125&to%5B%5D=683330370&"

i.e. I want 596254125 and 683330370.

How can I get it via rejex

I have tried this

```
 map = re.split(r"&to%5B%5D=\d+&", request)
```

This is not working. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use regex when there is a [dedicated function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parseqs) to parse url query strings for you:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

map = parse_qs(request)
to = map['to[]']
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> request = 'request=1417935385131095&to%5B%5D=596254125&to%5B%5D=683330370&e2e=%7B%22submit_0%22%3A1394711375644%7D'
>>> map = parse_qs(request)
>>> map['to[]']
['596254125', '683330370']
```